# windows 8 screen shutting off too soon

Tags: windows-8, power-management

I went to the power options and changed the settings to make it wait ten minutes before shutting off the screen, but the screen still shuts off after a minute,

I've tried setting different time limits and it doesn't seem to make a difference, the computer's screen still shuts off after 1 minute.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are we talking about sleep here?

Comment: @mwong no the screen just shuts off

Comment: When you return to the power options window, does it indicate that the delay is still set to 10 minutes?

Comment: did u make sure u changed settings for the power mode you are currently on? Also did u check if the settings u changed reflected both battery and plugged-in modes?

Comment: @AbhishekGirish yes, yes, its the same for both (20mins)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison before it was reseting now the utility seems to have accepted the changes but is still doing the wrong thing

Comment: Have you got any other tools/drivers/apps handling the power options (usually something from your OEM)?

Comment: @Peter Turned out had a lenovo power manager that was interfering with it disabling it solved the problem write it up as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: @user168768 Thanks and glad I could help. Added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of reasons I can think of are either there is an incompatible driver, or you are using some app which is taking control of the power options.

e.g if you have applications like vlc media player running in the background with even a paused video it will block the screen from shutting off.

Comment: Its definitely some app taking control and not letting your screen to shut off.

Comment: How can this be the answer when the problem is that the monitor shuts off, not stays on?

Answer (score 8):

This was way trickier than I expected. You need to alter one registry value:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7]\Attributes
>
> Value Data = 2 (0x00000002)

After that, go back to your power settings in "Power Options" - "Advanced Power Settings". Now go to the "Display" item and a new option appears. It says "Console lock display off timeout" set this value and everything will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any other tools, drivers or apps that handle power options. Sometimes OEMs will add these. If you installed drivers with an installer taken from their website, it might have installed these tools alongside.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your screensaver settings? Make sure it is not set to start a blank screensaver after every one minute.

Answer (score 0):

##### Answering in 2022

If your user account is an "Active Directory" account (if you are logging into a Windows Domain) then you might be unfortunate enough to be working at a company where the IT department thinks they can play god on each employee's computer under some ill-conceived notion of security. They are responsible for this annoyance.

Using RegEdit you can go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", create a DWORD value named "DisableLockWorkstation", set the value to 1, restart the computer, and then ***avoid logging into the domain***.

You will notice that the problem will be gone.

Unfortunately, next time you log into the domain the problem will return, because the geniuses at your IT department have created administrative domain policies that cause this setting to be reset each time.

There are ways to prevent administrative domain policies from being applied, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your secured lock time setting needs readjusting.  Go to Applications> Settings> Lock Screen> Secured lock time.

Take a look at those settings and see and you get the results that you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Note this is for Winodows 8.1 .
 I looked at all these answers and nobody explained it properly so I had to figure it out myself.
What you have to do is go to **Control Panel** (you can do a search for it). In the Control Panel select **Personalization**. Then on the bottom right hand corner, you might have to scroll down, is the **Screen Saver** item.  Select that and a box will appear, then set the amount of time you want to wait for the screen saver.
Hit **Apply**, then **OK**.
Done

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.