# Windows 10 Goes to Lock Screen after 1 Minute

Tags: windows-10, login, lock-screen, logout

This began a few days ago and I am struggling to figure out what is causing my Windows to jump to the lock screen after 60 seconds of inactivity. Each time, the lock screen appears and requires me to enter the password again.

#### Investigation/Things I have tried so far:

1. Reset the Power Options in control panel. I have tried using other power plans, creating a new one, etc. with no luck
2. Enabling "System unattended sleep timeout" and setting it to 60 minutes as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1019043/windows-10-sleeps-before-set-time/1023836#1023836)
3. Enabling "Console lock display off timeout" and setting it to 60 minutes as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/495922/windows-8-screen-shutting-off-too-soon/525500#525500)
4. Setting "Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit" within Local Computer Policy to 900 seconds as explained [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-auto-locks-after-1-minute/403866b5-8896-4cb2-9b6a-dae1fbef9c87)
5. Added the "DisableLockWorkstation" option in registry as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/395708/windows-7-disable-lock-workstation-after-10-minutes-using-group-policy)
6. Disabling Sysinternals [Autologon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon)

fwiw, there are two strange messages in the Windows Sign-in page. Could they be a hint as to what's going on? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt0yc.png)

Comment: All of these options are listed in things I've tried, except perhaps Screen Saver - which was changed to 20 minutes, then disabled altogether, with no effect.

Comment: You might wish to update BIOS, Chipset (if there is one) and Power Driver. With respect the red sign on message, is this a company machine?

Comment: Will check bios and report back. It's not a company machine but we recently changed IT providers at work and I asked them to setup my personal computer to work seamlessly with OneDrive, Office, etc. and in doing so they remoted in and installed SentinelOne and Rapid7, which made me think that had something to do with this setting change. Although the company machines don't have this timeout limit...

Comment: See if you can find a solution in these Super User [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1214447/prevent-windows-10-from-locking-when-monitor-turns-off)

Comment: None of those worked